# SQL select Count with where very slow

Tags: sql, performance, linq, count

I use a `count()` function many times in my program:

```
var housewith2floor = from qry in houses
where qry.floor == 2
select qry;

var counthousewith2floor = housewith2floor.count();

var housecolorwhite = from qry in house
where qry.color == "white"
select qry;

var countwhotehouse = housecolorwhite.count();
```

Each `count` method takes a lot of time to be executed.  The database has 2 millions rows of data. I already put an unclustered index for floor column and color column, but the count still takes too long. Is there any other way I can make my count run much faster?

Comment: Haven't played with LINQ much (just a little with EF) but I bet you could speed up the count by doing it on the DB side versus in your code behind.

Comment: What is the isolation level on the dbcontext?

Comment: Check what's actually being run against the database.  Either run a trace or put a breakpoint at `var housecolorwhite` and hover over `counthousewith2floor`.

Comment: i used ReadUncommitted for the isolationlevel but still slow...

Comment: Is this considerably slower than a direct SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much the count that takes time. The initial statement won't actually execute until it needs to (called [deferred execution](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_linq/article.php/c16935/Understanding-LINQs-Deferred-Execution.htm)). So it's the query generated by

```
var housewith2floor = from qry in houses
where qry.floor == 2
select qry;
```

that takes the time.

Edit to remove statment about indexes as I see you have already created them.

Are there any tables which reference or are referenced by "houses", and do they use Lazy Loading?

Comment: there are only 1 table which is house, and the datacontext is re-used for other query ( 10 query use the same datacontext.house )..  yes, the query use lazy loading , the query will only be executed when the .count() is called..